# MVC 4 MetaClass Markup not showing up in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View that loads a few partial views at load time depending on a database. It's working great so far with one exception: because this is a database first situation, I'm using a meta class to add the appropriate markup to the model fields. It worked perfectly fine when I had all the stuff on a single page but since I broke it out into partials, it refuses to recognize the meta class anymore.

There's a lot of unrelated code everywhere so I've broken out the important stuff (some names have been changed to protect the innocent)...

In the view to load said partials:

```
foreach (var p in MyProject.Controllers.UtilityController.GetPViews())
    { 
        @Html.Partial("../Partial/" + p.ViewName, new ViewDataDictionary { { "column", "column" + p.ColumnSize } })
    }
```

The main part of the meta class:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class MyProjectData_Meta
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MyProjectData_Meta))]
    public partial class MyProjectData
    {
        public class MyProjectData_Meta
        {
             //Gets and sets and stuff. For example:
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name.")]
            [Display(Name = "First Name")]
            [UIHint("FloatLabel")]
            public string MemberFirstName { get; set; }
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

And finally the code that pulls the list from said database...

```
public static List<ModuleList> GetPViews()
    {
        MyProjectEntities pv = new MyProjectEntities();
        List<ModuleList> lvl = pv.ModuleLists.OrderBy(s => s.PageOrder).ToList();

        return lvl;
    }
```

So is there some glaring detail I'm missing or more information you need from me in order to tell me where I'm being stupid?

**EDIT**: Doh! Forgot to put in my actual view code:

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyProjectData

<div class="@ViewBag.column">
<fieldset id="fsBasic">
    <legend>Basic Information</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberFirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemberFirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberFirstName)
    </div>
</div>
```

To answer the other question: I know it's not using the meta class because the LabelFor is showing "MemberFirstName" instead of "First Name" which is what it does actually do when I'm not using a partial class.

Comment: MetadataType is used mostly when you use `DisplayFor` or `EditorFor`. Since there is no example code that uses these methods, there is no way to determine what is wrong.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How do you know it is not recognizing it?

Comment: Updated the original post to answer your questions

Comment: And by single file do you mean multiple partial c# files (.cs) or partial views?

Comment: And what about when you call regular htmlhelper methods like textboxfor (instead of the editorfor or displayfor)? Does it work in that case or same thing?

Comment: Mike: Yes, when there were no partial views at all it worked just fine. As soon as I started breaking the elements out into partial views, the meta stuff stopped working.

Regular HTML helper methods work just fine in the partial views.